# Specific URL parameter leads to "You don't have permission to access this resource"

Tags: php, lamp

Very confusing one this...

On the test subdomain only (so NOT on live), any URL which has parameters including `%20desc` returns the error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Doesn't seem to be anything to do with the actual content of the page... I can literally put up a one line text file containing only "Hello" up in a page and it happens:

[image: Working version without parameter]

vs

[image: Broken version with parameter]

and it works fine on my live www subdomain:

[image: Live version]

The test subdomain is on the same linux server... it's literally just in a parallel folder with an identical copy of the site.

Absolutely baffled... anybody?

*Additional thing I've noticed if it helps... it doesn't need the whole "%20desc" to break it... it's down to the presence of just "0desc".  Other similar values such as "%20asc" do not cause the problem... just "0desc".

Comment: show test1.php code

Comment: It's difficult (if not impossible) to tell what's happening without more information. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/10601203) (TL;DR, the answer is no).

Comment: test1.php is literally a text file containing nothing but "hello"... not even any html.

The idea was that it would be minimal and reproducible, but if there's a better way to do it let me know!

Comment: @A1Dan Sure it's minimal and reproducible, until you fix it. The purpose of StackOverflow is to build a repository of searchable questions and answers. If you fix it or the links you've posted [rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), your question will no longer demonstrate the problem you're looking to find a solution to, which is a problem for future readers. Please see the second link I posted which talks more about this.

Comment: As for the actual problem, based on the information you've provided, the only reasonable explanation I can come to is that given the PHP code is never executed, whatever web server you're using is blocking the request for one reason or another.

Comment: Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem:  The test1.php literally contains 6 characters, not sure I can go much more minimal.

Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself: Going to the relevant URL is the only way I know of to reproduce the problem.  As stated, it doesn't even happen on my live subdomain, so would not expect anybody else to be able to reproduce it elsewhere.

Reproducible - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem: It does

Comment: @A1Dan It's not in the question though is it? It's on an external website. If you can't provide a reproducible example, at least provide a better explanation of what you've tried and what technologies you're using.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely not a PHP issue, but something to do with the web server.  Sadly, my skills are much more towards the former!

Comment: Fair point about it getting fixed in future, but I can't think of any other way of demonstrating the problem other than with the external link?

Comment: @A1Dan If you're unable to make it reproducible outside of your website, the second best option would probably be to just demonstrate the behavior within your question with the use of screenshots and example URLs. It would also be helpful to include a better explanation of what you've tried and the technologies you're using (mainly what web server and how this environment differs from the other one that is working).

Comment: Cool, have replaced the links with screenshots.

Also added the detail that there are essential no known / intended differences between live and test... just two folders in the same environment.

Comment: @A1Dan Are there any logs you could share?

Comment: Nothing going to my error_log file... not sure if there are any server logs I should be checking?

Comment: You mentioned the only difference is that they're in different folders. Is it possible that the user account the web server is running under has more restrictive permissions on the test folder than the other one?

Comment: What webserver are you using? Is it apache? If so can you provide your virtualhost configuration and .htaccess files?

Comment: It's a hosted linux apache server... which can limit my access to config etc, but I'll get onto the support guys and see if they can provide

Comment: the issue is definitely with your hosting provider and not related to php as far as I can see. Hopefully your hosing provider support team can provide an htaccess override that resolves your issue. Or maybe you will be restircted on your paramters you can use and have to change those. Either way I don't think stackoverflow will be able to help you. Best of luck.

Comment: For some reason the test directory had a much larger .htaccess file than the live one.  So I copied the live one over the test one... but it's not made any difference.

Comment: You're right there Oxymoron, definitely hosting related not php.  Was hoping somebody on Stackoverflow may have enough apache knowledge to suggest why a seemingly random series of characters in a URL parameter would lead to this "forbidden" error

Comment: BTW, I've now discovered it doesn't have to be "0desc".... any number will do, eg "7desc" or "149desc".  But anything shorter / different, such as "0des" or "0asc" does not cause the error.